# Do you name a dictionary by the key or the value?

Tags: naming, naming-standards, dictionary

Do you name a dictionary by the key or the value? I have a dictionary that will hold gradient data and the component:

```
dictionary[gradient] = component;
```

Do I name it gradientDictionary or componentDictionary?

Comment: How about naming it "gradientToComponent" or "gradientToComponentDictionary"? (;

Comment: I usually go with `componentByGradient`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That depends, but generally I'd suggest naming by the values. The keys are often just a way to quickly find what you are actually looking for and will be using.

Depending on context, for your specific example, I'd also probably suggest just calling the dictionary `components` to avoid encoding too much type information in the name.

Comment: Additional, if more than one map is used to find components - rare but it happens - add a "ByFoo" suffix to distinguish them. E.g. `componentsByName[name]` and `componentsByID[id]`. It will be visually clear when the wrong one is used, as the matching parts are next to each other: `componentsByName[id]`.